# Mimicking Python generator, with IO, in Haskell

Tags: haskell

This is a question about how to do something in Haskell, that is easy to do in Python3.

I have a Python3 program that uses generators, as follows:

```
def gen(filename):
    for line in open(filename):
        line = line.rstrip()
        print(f"From {filename} about to yield the line {line}")
        yield line
        print(f"From {filename} recently yielded the line {line}")
        if "." in line:
            yield from gen(line)

for line in gen("a.txt"):
    print(f"Main program has {line}")
```

If I give it an input file a.txt containing the following:

```
First line of a
b.txt
Third line of a
```

and another input file b.txt containing the following:

```
First line of b
Second line of b
```

then the output, as I would expect, is:

```
From a.txt about to yield the line First line of a
Main program has First line of a
From a.txt recently yielded the line First line of a
From a.txt about to yield the line b.txt
Main program has b.txt
From a.txt recently yielded the line b.txt
From b.txt about to yield the line First line of b
Main program has First line of b
From b.txt recently yielded the line First line of b
From b.txt about to yield the line Second line of b
Main program has Second line of b
From b.txt recently yielded the line Second line of b
From a.txt about to yield the line Third line of a
Main program has Third line of a
From a.txt recently yielded the line Third line of a
```

I would very much like to be able to do the same thing in Haskell. I need to preserve the basic structure of the Python version, keeping gen() as a function (or semi-coroutine, if you want to call it that) that I can call from various different places.

In my attempts to write it in Haskell, I am getting in a dreadful mess with types like:

```
IO [IO String]
```

and I suspect that I'm going about it the wrong way.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm not experienced enough in Haskell to know a good way to get an equivalent to Python generators - but with that particular type you can use the `sequence` function and `fmap` it over the `IO` to get a `IO IO [String]`, then use `join` to reduce to an `IO [String]` which I assume is the type you want.

Answer (score 10):

The data type you're looking for is [`FreeT`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/free-5.1/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Free.html#t:FreeT):

```
data FreeF f a b = Pure a | Free (f b)
newtype FreeT f m a = FreeT { runFreeT :: m (FreeF f a (FreeT f m a)) }
```

`FreeT f m a` represents "alternating layers of `m` followed by `f`, except at any point, instead of a `f`-layer, there can be a terminating `a`-value". The specific form of this type that equates to your generators is

```
type Generator a = FreeT ((,) a) IO ()
```

A `Generator a` is alternating layers of `IO`-computation and `a`-production, except one of the `IO`-computations can terminate generation by producing a `()` instead.

```
instance (Functor f, Monad m) => Monad (FreeT f m)
instance MonadTrans (FreeT f)
lift :: (MonadTrans t, Monad m) => m a -> t m a
lift :: Monad m => m a -> FreeT f m a
liftF :: (Functor f, MonadFree f m) => f a -> m a
liftF :: (Functor f, Monad m) => f a -> FreeT f m a
```

So you can write `gen` in this manner:

```
-- singleton generator
yield :: a -> Generator a
yield x = liftF (x, ())
-- empty generator (unused/part of when)
end :: Generator a
end = return ()
gen :: FilePath -> Generator String
gen path = do handle <- lift $ openFile path
              fileLines <- lift $ lines <$> hGetContents handle
              forM_ fileLines $ \line -> do
                  lift $ putStrLn $ "From " ++ path ++ " about to yield the line " ++ line
                  yield line
                  lift $ putStrLn $ "From " ++ path ++ " recently yielded the line " ++ line
                  when ('.' `elem` line) $ gen line
              lift $ hClose handle
```

You can then tear this structure back down:

```
main = iterT (\(line, continue) -> putStrLn ("Main program has " ++ line) >> continue)
             (gen "a.txt")
```

`FreeT` has a cousin, named [`Stream`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/streaming-0.2.2.0/docs/Streaming.html#t:Stream). This is pretty much the same thing, except it uses some tricks to squeeze some more performance out. (The cost is that equality is now fuzzier than before, but we don't usually care about equality of control structures anyway.) Specifically, instead of alternating `m` and `f` layers, `Stream` is just a sequence of `m` and `f` layers in whatever order they're created in. As long as `Monad m`, this is fine, as adjacent `m` layers can always be `join`ed together and new `pure` ones formed between adjacent `f`-layers, until the alternating structure of `FreeT` is recovered.

If you use `Stream` (which you probably should), then you may want to replace `(,)` with [`Of`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/streaming-0.2.2.0/docs/Data-Functor-Of.html#t:Of), from the same package:

```
data Of a b = !a :> b
type Generator a = Stream (Of a) IO ()
```

The strictness isn't particularly useful with `String`, but it does read better. It's more useful for other types, like `Int`.